# Debugging using console Input

Tags: java, eclipse

How one would be able to *debug the Java program using ecllipse IDE which takes the input using  scanner*. I have search this on google but doesn't find any appropriate solution. The problem is that I was stuck into an null pointer exception while reading the input , so I want to debug my program.

This is my program...

```
package p;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;

import java.math.*;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

           int T = in.nextInt();
           int[][] ar = new int[T][];
           for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
               int n;
               {
                    n = in.nextInt();
               }
           for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
               {
                ar[i][j]=in.nextInt(); /*null pointer exception occurs here*/
               }
           }


        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {   int count=0,i1,k;
            for(int j=1;j<ar[i].length;j++)
            {
                k=ar[i][j];
                for(i1=j-1; i1>=0 && k<ar[i][i1]; i--)
                    ar[i][i1+1]=ar[i][i1];
                ar[i][i1+1]=k;
                count++; 
            }
        System.out.println(count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, _Debug this java program which gets input from a scanner, using eclipse IDE_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never say(*by initializing*) how many cols will `ar[i][j]` will have (so accessing those uninitialized memory block surely gives `NullPointerException`
do this for all `i` rows 
`ar[i] = new int[colSize]`

check [this link](http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/) as well

Comment: @downvoter care to comment what was wrong may be I missed something

Comment: yes its working now, previously I was using unintialized or unallocated memory that's why i was getting the Null Pointer exception but stil working on to decrease time complexity.

Comment: @girishlalwani2010 If it did solved your NPException then you can mark this answer as approved - that would be beneficial for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Check out a tutorial on [debugging using eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

You need to enter debugging mode after setting some break points. Break points are spots in your code you want the debugger to stop so you can view what's currently stored in various variables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check the javadoc for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and use the `hasNext()` methods to make sure it has the input you expect

Answer (score 0):

Just put a break point where you want, then run it with Debug .It does not matter programme step contains Scanner or not. Even if you come across scanner statemenet, you just type a line on concole input, then enter. Programme will continue.